# No such file or directory in docker container

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, centos7

I have committed docker container as image with list of node and perl files.

```
rm/node             4.0                 22d40a764333        2 days ago          1.376 GB
```

Below are the contents in rm/node:4.0 image

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost docker_test]$ docker run -it rm/node:4.0
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.


[root@2d6c97a0a416 /]# ls -lrt Reader_Manager/SISPlatform/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   61 Jun  2 20:49 Dev-SSL
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   40 Jun  2 20:49 sis-auth
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root   86 Jun  2 20:49 logs
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   89 Jun  2 20:49 build_scripts
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   83 Jun  2 20:49 StopAllServices.bat
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  174 Jun  2 20:49 StartAllServices.bat
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  104 Jun  2 20:49 SISMA
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  104 Jun  2 20:49 SISCS
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:27 Auth
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:28 SISRM
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:29 SEOS-TSMWrapper
```

Created new image rm/node:5.0 using below dockerfile.

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost docker_test]$ cat Dockerfile
FROM rm/node:4.0
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3030
EXPOSE 7030

WORKDIR /root/Reader_Manager/SISPlatform
```

But unable to run the script as it said no such file or directory.

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost docker_test]$ docker run rm/node:5.0 perl build_scripts/devdeploy.pl
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
Can't open perl script "build_scripts/devdeploy.pl": No such file or directory
```

So i checked inside the rm/node:5.0 image. By default it went into workdir as mentioned in dockerfile. but it doesnt contain any of the files from rm/node:4.0

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost docker_test]$ docker run -it rm/node:5.0
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
[root@b546a939be6e SISPlatform]# ls
[root@b546a939be6e SISPlatform]#
```

Comment: Isn't the path to your script supposed to be /Reader_Manager/SISPlatform instead of /root/Reader_Manager/SISPlatform ?

Comment: Yes. you are right. Thank you @Derek